# API to disable NFC in Android app immediately

Tags: java, android, react-native, nfc

I am trying to determine how an Android app can stop the phone from broadcasting NFC signals at any particular time.

I know that this is possible because I am using an app where when a particular modal screen is opened NFC no longer functions. I know this is happening because if I hold up the phone to my NFC reader when the modal is open, nothing is recognised. As soon as I close the modal, the NFC reader instantly picks up the device.

I am unsure how to integrate this into my app. I have read other answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29608545/2273902) which seem to state it's not possible, which can't be true because I'm seeing it happen before my eyes.

Is [NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode) what I am looking for? I am trying to determine if this will work but as I'm unsure how to implement it I can't test it.

Comment: That app may be attempting [Android Beam](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#p2p) which would be sending a NFC message that the receiver in your video is unable to interpret.

Comment: @MorrisonChang That sounds plausible. If the app attempts Android Beam, would that stop the reader from detecting the phone?

Comment: If the reader doesn't know how to deal with Android Beam, the default action may be do nothing which I believe is the desired behavior. You could always setup a Android Beam client on a different device to test that particular modal app.

Comment: @MorrisonChang It turns out `enableReaderMode` was correct as per my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to disable NFC by using `enableReaderMode` as I originally thought. After adding the code below into my React Native application's overridden `onCreate` method, I was able to disable NFC throughout the app.

```
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    adapter.enableReaderMode(this, null, NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF, null);
}
```

Comment: This is technically not correct because you're passing a STATE_ where a FLAG_ should be. I just so happens that that STATE_OFF value is the same as a FLAG_ value, and that putting it into reader mode even with that flag works by change. you should pass 0.